# Where do I get servlet-api.jar from?

Tags: servlets

In order to write servlets code I need servlet-api.jar.
Where do i get servlet-api.jar from ?

Comment: Related (and very important): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure that you're using the same Servlet API specification that your Web container supports. Refer to this chart if you're using Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

The Web container that you use will definitely have the API jars you require.

Tomcat 6 for example has it in `apache-tomcat-6.0.26/lib/servlet-api.jar`

Comment: For those with Tomcat 7, you'll probably find the lib directory in /usr/share/tomcat7/lib

Comment: How do i know what Servlet API specification my Web container supports? Also: what's a Web container, and where do i get one?

Answer (score 13):

Grab it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api)

Just choose required version and click 'Binary'. e.g direct link to  [version 2.5](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar)

Comment: This should get the checkmark if you just want the jar, no muss no fuss.  Awesome!

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider using Java EE, which includes the `javax.servlet.*` packages.  If you require a specific version of the servlet api, for instance to target a specific web application server, you will probably want the Java EE version which matches, see [this version table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet#History).

Answer (score 2):

You can find a recent servlet-api.jar in Tomcat 6 or 7 lib directory. If you don't have Tomcat on your machine, download the binary distribution of version 6 or 7 from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi