# ServletException cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

Error in java file i am getting as  ServletException cannot be resolved to a type

Multiple markers at this line 
    - HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a 
     type
    - HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved to 
     a type

Please le me know if any jar is missing

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(req,resp);
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are not created a web project. If so , servlet.jar is missing.

Comment: http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/servlet/ServletException.html

Comment: welcome to SOF. You need to `import` them before use them! or you need to add their `jar` into your build path before `import`

Answer (score 0):

You lack the servlet-api jar provided by your targeted servlet container (for example tomcat)

see [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

and

[Where do I get servlet-api.jar from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521851/where-do-i-get-servlet-api-jar-from)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the folowing imports to your servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

And add the following jar into your classpath:

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

Answer (score 0):

Add `jsp-api.jar` and `servlet-api.jar` to your build path.